# how to show json formated data in GridView

Tags: yii2

I want to show json formated data in gridview. I have following:

Json Data:

```
[{"c_id":1,"c_name":"Marokand","c_logo":"Marokand","c_slogan":"Marokand","c_address":"Tashkent Amir Temur, Uzbekistan","c_website":"www.maroqand.uz","c_email":"info@maroqand.uz","c_owner":"someone",},{"c_id":2,"c_name":"Apple LLC","c_logo":"","c_slogan":"","c_address":"","c_website":"","c_email":"","c_owner":""}
```

In my view file, I have following code:

```
 <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            'c_id',
            'c_name',
            'c_logo',
            'c_slogan',
            'c_address',
            // 'c_website',
            // 'c_email:email',
            // 'c_owner',
            // 'c_short_description:ntext',
            // 'c_description:ntext',
            // 'c_history:ntext',
            // 'c_goal:ntext',
            // 'cci_memerbship_id',

            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
```

How can I show json data in gridview?

Comment: You can got through the YII official documentation.
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/

Comment: Be more specific .. show a pratical sample and a proper question ..

Answer (score 1):

Use ArrayDataProvider: [Refer Link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-providers.html#array-data-provider)

On controller file first decode json data like this and init data provider:

```
use yii\data\ArrayDataProvider;
use yii\helpers\Json;

$data = Json::decode("YOUR JOSN DATA", true);

$dataProvider = new ArrayDataProvider([
  'allModels' => $data,
  'pagination' => [
  'pageSize' => 10,
],
  'sort' => [
    'attributes' => ['c_id'],
  ],
]);
```

on view side:

```
 <?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        'c_id',
        'c_name',
        'c_logo',
        'c_slogan',
        'c_address',
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```